# How do I add links to nested div tags without nesting the anchors as well?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add hover effects to change the background color of each of the div once an anchor tag is applied.

The problem is that I don't know how do it without the anchor tags being nested. And even then, I don't get the desired results.

Feel free to fiddle with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/69nTS/

This fiddle has been edited by doktorgradus and is closer to what I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/nFUmY/1/

Your help is much appreciated!

Here is the CSS:

```
#team-container {
width: 770px;
}
/*    #inner-container {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 766px;
}*/
.first {
    background-color: #6f6f6f;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.second {
    margin: 4px 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:150px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    background-color: #aaa;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.third {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.fourth {
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 118px;
    font-style: italic;
}
.first, .second, .third, .fourth {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 6px 0;
}
.third, .fourth {
    margin: 4px 8px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div id="team-container">
<div class="first">General Services Agency</div>
<!--<div id="inner-container">-->
<div class="second">Administration &amp;
    <br />Finance
    <div class="third">Central Mail</div>
    <div class="third">Finance</div>
    <div class="third">Purchasing</div>
</div>
<div class="second">Airports
    <div class="third">Finance</div>
    <div class="third">Operations</div>
</div>
<div class="second">General Services
    <div class="third">Architectural Services</div>
    <div class="third">Facility Services
        <div class="fourth">Custodial Day</div>
        <div class="fourth">Custodial Night</div>
        <div class="fourth">Maintenance 1</div>
        <div class="fourth">Maintenance 2</div>
        <div class="fourth">Surplus</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">Finance</div>
    <div class="third">Fleet Services</div>
    <div class="third">Real Property</div>
</div>
<div class="second">Information Technology
    <div class="third">Administration &amp; Finance
        <div class="fourth">Service Desk</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">Applications
        <div class="fourth">EFS</div>
        <div class="fourth">Law &amp; Justice</div>
        <div class="fourth">Property/Tax</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">Infrastructure
        <div class="fourth">Communications</div>
        <div class="fourth">Desktop Services</div>
        <div class="fourth">Health Agency IT</div>
        <div class="fourth">Network &amp; Servers</div>
        <div class="fourth">Operations</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">Project Management Office</div>
</div>
<div class="second">Parks
    <div class="third">Finance</div>
    <div class="third">Dairy Creek
        <br />Golf Course</div>
    <div class="third">Morro Bay
        <br />Golf Course</div>
    <div class="third">Operations
        <div class="fourth">Huasna District</div>
        <div class="fourth">Mesa District</div>
        <div class="fourth">Pecho District</div>
        <div class="fourth">Salinas District</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">Planning</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is the desired result you are looking for?

Comment: see the response below with my updated fiddle. I want to add anchor tags to each of the divs with a hover effect so that you could click anywhere in the div and it will go to the link.

Comment: Div is a block element. A is an inline element. Block elements can contains inline elements, but (by standard) inline elements can`t contains block elements.

Comment: I had initially accepeted doktorgradus' answer below, but realized that it was incomplete. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hover effects on pure CSS (if I understand your question):

```
`.second:hover {
    background-color: #aee;
 }
 .third:hover {
     background-color: #eae;
 }

 .fourth:hover {
     background-color: #eea;
 }`
```

Comment: That is the idea, thank you! However I want each area to link to its respective page when clicking anywhere in that area, not just on the text.

Comment: Hm. Replace divs with anchors where is no nested links and add anchors where it is. Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nFUmY/

Comment: I tried applying that principle to go up one more level and only the text for both Airport and General Services is linked, not the entire area. How do I fix it?

Comment: It also only links the text on Facility Services, not the whole area.

Answer (score 0):

Here is both div highlighting and "Central Mail" is linked to google.  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69nTS/5/)

You simply nest the div inside the anchor, not the other way around.

```
<a href="http://google.com"><div class="third">Central Mail</div></a>
```

Also the CSS for hover on one of the classes:

```
.third:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

I cleared the usual stylings for an anchor to prevent underline and coloring:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: initial;
}
```

Comment: That is where i started but how do I link Central Mail's parent(Admin and Finance) to its own page without causing nested <a> tags?

The result is that it kicks it out. See Here: http://jsfiddle.net/69nTS/6/

Comment: @WeaponX What problem do you have with nesting the tags?  I've changed the parent link to yahoo.com so you can see that both anchors work independently despite the nesting: http://jsfiddle.net/69nTS/7/

Comment: but the subcategories have now been moved outside of the parent. and it is not in accordance with standards.

Comment: I see.  I guess I never realized nesting interactive content within an anchor was illegal.  It seems like to achieve proper standards you would need to do some work with CSS and absolute positioning to get it to lay out right but not be nested.  Which begs the question why are nested anchors illegal when the work around causes what I would consider less stable layouts...

Comment: I would guess because of how the different browsers handle it. Chrome used the parent link location for the whole area and the nested links locations were ignored (the hover effects were still applied) IE just separated the two elements like you saw in the fiddle.

Comment: Subterfuge wrote right way to solve problem. Search on SO for `nested anchors` or write javascript to process clicks on div.

Comment: I would love to use javascript, but I'm finding that the :hover pseudoclass applied to div does not work in IE9 unless there is an anchor tag in the div.